# 422 Unprocessable Entity Response in Webchat ID changing

Tags: http, response, http-status-code-422

I'm trying to do some automation on a shopping platform to automatically send messages when order is received. However I realise that i'm getting Response 422 when there is no conversation existing between me and the buyer. If there is a conversation, it will be fine getting 200.

I tried to use the exact same headers and body in Postman and whenever I try to change the buyer ID to the buyer without any existing conversation, i'm getting 422 again. 
Is there any possibility that I could make it go through? [image]

Comment: `422` generally means there's something wrong with your JSON body, either the properties you are using or the values you are specifying. The answer to this is not really general to HTTP or APIs but is going to depend on the specific API you are using. Best is probably consult their documentation to make sure you're really sending the correct thing and if that fails consult their support system.

Comment: Yup I assume it's the values that i'm specifying aka the buyer ID. It's not an open platform but something I'm trying to achieve by myself. Does it mean that the way that the API process doesn't allow my value?